# nginx ingress "sometimes" returns 502

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I serve static files through an nginx instance there's also another nginx instance acting as an ingress controller. It's provided by my cloud provider.
Sometimes when I hit the  page the network tab in the page inspector (in google chrome: `ctrl+maj+i`) mentions 502 error on some static files.

- If I press `f5` the errors disappear
- If I press `ctrl + f5`, some errors reappear (**not** always the same files), until I press `f5` gain
- If I look up the nginx ingress logs (`kubectl logs ingress_pod_name -n kube-system`), I see two cases: 1. multiples lines of 502 `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`, then 200 at some point, 2. multiple lines of 502 and that's it
- If I enter the url of a static file in the browser (e.g mywebsite.cloud/static/css.css) I can always see it, repeating `f5` or `ctrl + f5` does not change that. **But**, the ingress logs shows 502 errors and `ctrl + f5` shows me a "favicon.ico" 404 not found in the inspector's network tab, I don't think it's relevant but it's weird that it appears whenever there's a 502
- Lastly my nginx instance serving the static files does not shows any 502 log errors

My service and ingress :

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - name: myapp-backend
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
    - name: myapp-frontend
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: myapp-nginx
      port: 8001
      targetPort: 8001
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  labels:
      app: myapp
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "10m"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.example.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /core
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port: 
              number: 9000
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/core_media|core_static/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port: 
              number: 8001
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

Comment: DO you have pod logs for the times that your getting the 502? those would be important to have for this

Comment: yes the only ones that nginx (the one serving the static files) show are either 304 or 200 codes, meaning there's something wrong between the ingress controller and the service

Comment: did you check the limit of your connections to the application ?
i mean if it gets a load of requests coming to the application i really think that he will deny the requests that cannot be handled aka the ingress controller couldn't get to one of the pods under the service. i guess that if they were three different services it would have remove the load they were getting

Comment: I don't know how to change the connection limit, I scaled the number of replica to 3 instead of 1 on the nginx deployment (the one serving static) it made things worse, I then made a separate service for it and it didn't change anything.